# Issue with UnsafePointer<Uint8> in SQLite project in Swift

Tags: ios, sqlite, pointers, swift

We are implementing SQLite in iOS, in Swift, without using wrappers or Objective-C bridging.  Everything works fine, except when doing a query and extracting the result. The issue is with the `UnsafePointer<UInt8>` that is returned from SQLite in Swift as follows:

```
var querySQL = "SELECT address, phone FROM CONTACTS WHERE NAME = 'myName'"
var cQuery = querySQL.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
var statement: COpaquePointer = nil
if sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactsDB, cQuery!, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
   if sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW {
   var address : UnsafePointer<UInt8> = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)
   var data = NSData(bytes: address, length: 10)
   var string = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
   println(string)
```

As you can see, we can convert the pointer to String if we know the length of the object (in this case 10)

To dig into this issue, I have the following example

```
let pointerFromString: UnsafePointer<Int8> = "xyz".cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let stringFromPointer = String.fromCString(anotherPointerFromString_Int8)                    println(stringFromPointer!)
```

Given that `CChar` is an alias of `Int8`, I can convert a `String` to `UnsafePointer<Int8>` using `.cStringUsingEncoding()`, and then back to `String` using `.fromCString(<UnsafePointer_CChar>)`

The problem is that my SQLite result is a `UnsafePointer_UInt8`, that can´t be used with `.fromCString()`

The bottom line question is: Is it possible to convert or cast a `UnsafePointer_UInt8` to `UnsafePointer_Int8`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This should work:

```
let address = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)
let string = String.fromCString(UnsafePointer<CChar>(address))
```

**Update for Swift 3 (Xcode 8),** compare [Swift 3: convert a null-terminated UnsafePointer<UInt8> to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39533320/swift-3-convert-a-null-terminated-unsafepointeruint8-to-a-string):

```
let string = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0))
```

**Update:**

`sqlite3_column_text()` returns an *implicitly unwrapped optional,* and that is why you can pass it to `String(cString:)` directly.

But according to [Column methods, error and NULL handling #41](https://github.com/crawshaw/sqlite/issues/41), the return value *can* be null (in an out-of-memory situation, or if called with a NULL column type). Therefore it is safer to do

```
if let text = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0) {
    let string = String(cString: text)
    // ...
} else {
    // sqlite3_column_text() returned NULL
}
```