# Swift 3: convert a null-terminated UnsafePointer<UInt8> to a string

Tags: swift, string

I have a c api that returns a null terminated string that is an array of type `unsigned char*` (which would correspond to `UnsafePointer<UInt8>`).

Swift has the initializer `String(validatingUTF8:)`, but the argument has to be `UnsafePointer<CChar>` (a.k.a. `UnsafePointer<Int8>`), and there is no trivial way to convert between the two.

How do I convert from this null-terminated c-string to a Swift string?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Swift 3, `String` has two initializers

```
public init(cString: UnsafePointer<CChar>)
public init(cString: UnsafePointer<UInt8>)
```

therefore it can be created from (null-terminated) sequences of both signed and unsigned characters. So

```
let s = String(cString: yourCharPointer)
```

should just work.

---

`String` has another initializer

```
public init?(validatingUTF8 cString: UnsafePointer<CChar>)
```

which *fails* on ill-formed UTF-8 sequences instead of replacing them
by the replacement characters. This init method has no counterpart
taking unsigned characters.

Taking the existing implementations in [CString.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/CString.swift) as examples, it is not too difficult to add this as an extension:

```
extension String {
    public init?(validatingUTF8 cString: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) {
        guard let (s, _) = String.decodeCString(cString, as: UTF8.self,
                                                repairingInvalidCodeUnits: false) else {
            return nil
        }
        self = s
    }
}
```

and then

```
if let s = String(validatingUTF8: yourCharPointer) {
    print(s)
} else {
    print("invalid UTF-8")
}
```

also works with (null-terminated) sequences of both signed and unsigned characters.

Comment: Got it. It was not appearing in my auto-complete.

Comment: In swift 5.7 with Xcode 14, init(validatingUTF8:... and init(cSting: ....  are deprecated :( , any suggestions for this change ?

Comment: @Ramin: My suggested `extension String { ... }` code does not use that method, but uses `String.decodeCString()`. Is there a problem with that code?