# 'init' is unavailable: use 'withMemoryRebound(to:capacity:_)' to temporarily view memory as another layout-compatible type

Tags: ios, swift, parsing, swift3

This issue just came up as I updated to Xcode 8 and Swift 3. After I opted to have the Swift 2 code to be transposed to Swift 3 this issue arose in the parse library I had previously imported(Kanna).

```
internal init(docPtr: xmlDocPtr, object: xmlXPathObject) {
        switch object.type {
        case XPATH_NODESET:
            let nodeSet = object.nodesetval
            if nodeSet == nil || nodeSet?.pointee.nodeNr == 0 || nodeSet?.pointee.nodeTab == nil {
                self = .none
                return
            }

            var nodes : [XMLElement] = []
            let size = Int((nodeSet?.pointee.nodeNr)!)
            for i in 0 ..< size {
                let node: xmlNodePtr = nodeSet!.pointee.nodeTab[i]!
                let htmlNode = libxmlHTMLNode(docPtr: docPtr, node: node)
                nodes.append(htmlNode)
            }
            self = .NodeSet(nodeset: XMLNodeSet(nodes: nodes))
            return
        case XPATH_BOOLEAN:
            self = .Bool(bool: object.boolval != 0)
            return
        case XPATH_NUMBER:
            self = .Number(num: object.floatval)
        case XPATH_STRING:
            self = .String(text: Swift.String(cString: UnsafePointer<CChar>(object.stringval)) ?? "")
            return
        default:
            self = .none
            return
        }
    }
```

This code is an internal init within an extension in the Kanna.swift file. The error happens specifically in here:

```
            self = .String(text: Swift.String(cString: UnsafePointer<CChar>(object.stringval)) ?? "")
```

The error message is:

> 'init' is unavailable: use 'withMemoryRebound(to:capacity:_)' to
>   temporarily view memory as another layout-compatible type.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: In your case it should be just `.String(text: Swift.String(cString: object.stringval))`

Comment: Thank you very much Martin.

Comment: What if it were to be `if let tagName = String(validatingUTF8: UnsafePointer((mem?.name)!))` ?

Comment: I have updated http://stackoverflow.com/a/39533628/1187415 to cover that case as well.