# 'init' is unavailable: use 'withMemoryRebound(to:capacity:_)'

Tags: swift, swift3, init, unsafe-pointers

Following Swift3, I'm getting an error on `UnsafePointer`.  The debugger's proposed solution is not really clear enough to do something with though.

I know `UnsafePointer` has been raised in a previous question [Issue with UnsafePointer in SQLite project in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25168030/issue-with-unsafepointeruint8-in-sqlite-project-in-swift) but I'm struggling to relate its answers to this problem.

Error:

```
'init' is unavailable: use 'withMemoryRebound(to:capacity:_)' to temporarily view memory as another layout-compatible type.
```

Code:

```
let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress) {
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0))
        }
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Did you read the Xcode 8 release notes? This is thoroughly explained IIRC.

Comment: Thanks guys.  Searching based on the error did not throw up these answers.  As for the documentation, I regularly check Apple docs but usually get generic descriptions and methods that link to other methods, without providing examples of how to use them.  It could be more accessible.