# Swift Sqlite3_column_text()

Tags: ios, database, swift, sqlite

```
if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "select a from aaa", -1, &q,nil) == SQLITE_OK {
    while sqlite3_step(q) == SQLITE_ROW {
        let res = sqlite3_column_text(q, 1)
        print(res)
    }
} else {
    print("NOT WORKING")
    NSLog("%s", sqlite3_errmsg(db))
}
```

In my table aaa I have a field named 'a' and values 1,2,3 as shown here :

[image]

I'm trying to put the values in an array or just print them, but when I print `(print(res))`, the values are just "`nil`".

How can I get the real values?

EDIT: the values (1,2,3) are strings and not intagers, that why i chose sqlite3_column_text() and not sqlite3_column_int()

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25168030/issue-with-unsafepointeruint8-in-sqlite-project-in-swift for how the result from sqlite3_column_text can be converted to a Swift String.

Comment: Shouldn't the first column have index 0 instead of 1?

Comment: try with index = 0 instead of 1, or use directly the name of column: `a`

Comment: I tried it with index = 0 with no success. It seems like the real problem is to convert sqlite3_column_text to swift string as @Martin R said

Answer (score 12):

SOLVED:

the problem was to convert the function sqlite3_column_text() to string and the solution in swift3 is:

```
let string = String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0))
```

Comment: So it was 0 index and conversion to string!!

Answer (score 0):

I think the data type of `a` is `Int` and you are fetching it as text `sqlite3_column_text`.

Try this instead: `sqlite3_column_int`

If doesn't work try these combinations:

- Int with row 0: `sqlite3_column_int(q, 0)`
- text with row 0 : `sqlite3_column_text(q, 0)`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I didn't write that before but the values are strings and not intagers (look the edited post).

Comment: try this : sqlite3_column_text(q, 0)